# Why did this new line just show up on my google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i am using the google maps API (v3).  I just realized that a new line showed up at the bottom of my map that says:

**Map Data 2010 AND, AfriGIS (Pty) Ltd, Europa Technologies, Inva, Geosysternas SRL, Maplink . . . .**

1. How do i get rid of this?
2. Its longer than my map so it gets truncated and looks weird, is there any way to fix this (if there is no way to do #1)

Comment: Is it permitted by the TOS to get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you may not get rid of that line. It was probably always there, but the copyright changed and got longer and you just noticed.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

> 7.4 (d) Proprietary Rights Notices. You agree that you will not remove, obscure, or alter any proprietary rights notices (including copyright and trademark notices, Terms of Use links, or Brand Features) that may be affixed to or provided through the Service. Where such notices are not affixed within the Service, you agree to display such notices according to the Maps APIs Documentation.

To fix this… make the map wider?
I don't think there's anything much you can do, since you may not tamper with that line.

Comment: The copyright changes depending on the area shown by the map.